# Strange maven compilation error while building project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Strange maven compilation error while building project.

Hi,
I'm facing a trivial but rather a very strange issue with respect to maven project build.
I'm using Intellij as the IDE.

I've a maven project A which has two maven modules B and C

```
A
|
|
|--B
|
|--C
```

The module C is a test module which has a dependency on module B.

Now, when I build the entire project using mvn clean install, it complains of "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin   error: cannot find symbol

However, there is no compilation error shown on intellij.

Additionally, to my surprise, my test runs without any issue.

I've tried to execute different intellij options viz. (re-import/sync/invalid caches and restart), but in vain.

I've also tried to play around with the version of maven-compiler-plugin.

Can someone please help me what can be the reason of the failure? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I checked that. And it doesn't complain on intellij ide.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/5221149)

Comment: It's an import line and it is in module B.

Comment: If intellij can find the library, and maven cannot, then your pom.xml file does not have the correct dependencies. What is the library, and what is the failed import, and where is it imported on your pom.xml?

Comment: Could it be that you added your Java file into `resources` instead of `java` folder? Or maybe you added manually a library/module in IDE project settings? Maven can't be wrong, so the problem lies somewhere in IDE.

Comment: Say Module B has a class XYZ, hence, in C's pom.xml, the dependency that I've added is the Module B. 
And the import statement is nothing, but the class XYZ

Comment: does the intellij project use the same jdk as maven on the command line? the "cannot find symbol error" usually points to the exact location. if it points to an import line then import of what? something specific to a jdk version? or another module?

Answer (score 0):

the issue was occuring due to spring boot maven plugin's repackage goal.

The repackage goal replaces the original jar with the repackaged one.

The reason for the compilation issue is that application classes are packaged in BOOT-INF/classes so that's why the dependent module couldn't load a repackaged jar's classes.

More info here :

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/repackage-classifier.html